# AngularJS ng-view does not display content through $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason,  doesn't seem to show the content requested by the $routeProvider.
I'm quite new to AngularJS so feel free to point out my stupidity.

**index.html:**

```
<div ng-cloak id="main" ng-app="route" ng-controller="routeCtrl">

<ng-view></ng-view> 

</div>
...
<script src="javascript/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="javascript/data.js"> </script>
<script src="javascript/route.js"> </script>
```

**data.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('route', ['ngRoute'])


app.controller('routeCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.array = [
           //array stuff here 
                   ]
})

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{templateUrl: 'partials/table.html'})
    .otherwise({template: "<div> not found </div>"})

}]);
```

-The only thing that displays is the header. I have a working {{ 1+1 }} in the same div to ensure angularjs isn't broken. 
 
-Going to http://localhost:8000/#/jjabdqyuwbdy does not do anything 
 
-The **table.html:** file is a simple table that ng-repeats the data off the $scope.array in **data.js**. It worked when I initially set it up before moving it to a seperate file.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you have commented part of `$scope.array` !  use unminified version of angular to see described errors!

Comment: I'm not sure why this does not work, but try these things to see if you can zero in on the problem:
1. Change the route for your partial to /test and see if that makes the route and fallback (otherwise) work again.
2. Test with an inline template again, instead of the partial.

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki I downloaded the unminified version and it sadly did not give me any console errors. Also, I have a proper array inside of `$scope.array`, the comment is for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Isn't there an error in the console ?

Comment: @MunchyYDL I moved **table.html** into the main directory and it did not help. I also moved the `ng-app=""` and `ng-controller=""` the `body` tag. I then tried `.when('/', {template: "hello"})`. What's interesting is that in the console, **table.html** does not seem to be loaded.

Comment: You said you had it working before you moved the template out to a separate file, can you go back to that state?

Does the routing work at all now, can you get to the .otherwise-clause in some way?

Comment: @MunchyYDL I moved the contents of **table.html** back into the **index.html** div. 
neither the `.otherwise({template: "<div> not found </div>"})` nor the
`.when('/anytext', {template: "<b>hello</b>"})` do anything when going to **http://localhost:8000/#/anytext**. If I try **http://localhost:8000/somethingotherthanindex.html** it gives me a 404 error

Comment: Could the problem be that you forgot to include angular-route.min.js?

Comment: I have created a working plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/5rjTsGdKlanDNddmxd6W?p=preview
I have changed the templateUrl to a template and it works. It may be that your path is simply wrong. Can you tell me if this works for you?

Comment: Thanks everyone. After a day of working at it, I found out that the route.js file was the culprit. I redownloaded a new copy off the angular website and now everything is good.

Comment: Oh ok, nice that it solved the issue. :)